# Elixir - possible to combine custom map types?

Tags: elixir

When defining types in an Elixir module, is it possible to merge two different map types, where one is a subset of the other? For example:

```
defmodule Test do
  @typep map_a :: %{foo: String.t(), bar: String.t()}
  @typep map_b :: %{foo: String.t(), bar: String.t(), baz: String.t()}
end
```

I'd like to indicate that the `map_b` type is a map that is essentially an instance of `map_a()` plus the additional `baz` key. I experimented with `Map.merge(map_a(), %{baz: String.t})` - that compiles, but when I inspect the types via `t(Test)`, I just get back exactly what I wrote,

```
@typep map_b :: Map.merge(map_a(), %{baz: String.t})
```

which doesn't give me insight into whether or not this really does what I'm aiming for.

Is using `Map.merge/2` (or anything similar) to combine custom map types a valid approach? If not, how might this be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Map.merge/2` won’t work for specs, it’s not a map actually, it’s just a similar syntax.

One might achieve the desired result with a bit of metaprogramming.

```elixir
defmodule Test do
  @map_a_type quote(do: [foo: String.t(), bar: String.t()])

  @typep map_a :: %{unquote_splicing(@map_a_type)}
  @typep map_b :: %{unquote_splicing(@map_a_type), baz: String.t()}
end
```

Comment: Ah, very cool, thanks! I was not familiar with `unquote_splicing`, this was very helpful and educational.

Comment: As always, you are 42 steps beyond anyone else @Aleksei !!

Comment: Building on top of this, how would one combine everything? Say I have a normal parametric type (that gets a type as arg and embeds as the type of a map: `@type amount(range) :: %{amount: range, currency: binary}`). Is there any way to quote/unquote/dance/sing/anything, so I can also define another parametric type based on extra keys (like `@type expense :: amount(0..100, extra: field)` that would result in `%{amount: 0..10, currency: binary, extra: field}`?

Comment: @rewritten I am not sure I follow the intent clearly, but I’d start with examining `quote(do: @type %{amount: 0..10, currency: binary, extra: field})` and tweaking it.